# How to format string in java with Formatter

Tags: java, android, decimalformat

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String test1 = new String("01,");
        final String test2 = new String("01,0");
        final String test3 = new String("1,00");

        String pattern = "##,##";
        DecimalFormat formatter;
        DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        dfs.setGroupingSeparator(',');

        formatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern, dfs);
        String result1 = formatter.format(test1);
        String result2 = formatter.format(test2);
        String result3 = formatter.format(test3);

        System.out.println("Result 1 == " + result1);
        System.out.println("Result 2 == " + result2);
        System.out.println("Result 3 == " + result3);
    }
}
```

I am trying to format the string. I added the code which I am using for formatting. I am getting exception.

**I want result as 01,00 for all of this.**

EXCEPTION -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:487)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:140)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

If anyone has any idea please guide me.

Comment: Please don't use `new String(String)` in Java, it is not only pointless but needlessly verbose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DecimalFormat.format` accepts only `Date` or `Number` objects, not `String`!

**EDIT-1:**

1) `String pattern = "00.00"`

2)

```
        String result1 = formatter.format(formatter.parse(test1));
        String result2 = formatter.format(formatter.parse(test2));
        String result3 = formatter.format(formatter.parse(test3));
```

For example:
for

```
    final String test1 = new String("01,");
    final String test2 = new String("02,3");
    final String test3 = new String("1,00");
```

it gives me:

```
Result 1 == 01,00
Result 2 == 02,30
Result 3 == 01,00
```

Comment: what is the type of formatter..

java.util.Formatter? I used this but its giving compile error.

Comment: format method has 2 and 3 arguments...it does not have single argument

Comment: @Scorpion, What compile error? This is just `DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern, dfs)`

Comment: Very well, could somebody explain his "-1"?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be used.

```
format = new DecimalFormat(".00");
format.format(10.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = (String.format("%,d", 1000000)).replace(',', ' ');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    int minutes = (int) secondsLeft / 60;
    int seconds = secondsLeft - minutes * 60;

    String upDatePattern ;
    upDatePattern = (String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds));
    timerTextView.setText(upDatePattern);

    this produces a zero padded "timer" with min/sec
     ex: 02:35
 you can find lots of formatting examples on "Formatter | Android Developers
```